# Aceptar solo 0,1,2 en un arreglo c#

Tags: c#

Como aceptar que se ingrese solo los numeros 0,1,2 en un arreglo de c#

```
        int elements;
        int[] values;
        Console.Write("Número de elementos: ");
        elements = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //Pide el número de elementos

            values = new int[elements]; //Inicializa el arreglo con los elementos indicados
            Console.Clear();
            Console.Write("Ingreso de datos: \n");

        for (int counter = 0; counter < elements; counter++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Elemento {0}: ", counter + 1); //Pide los valores de cada elemento
            values[counter] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrias simplemente validarlo, algo como esto

```
int counter = 0;

while(counter < elements)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Elemento {0}: ", counter + 1);
    string temp = Console.ReadLine();

    int valor = 0;
    if(!int.TryParse(temp, out valor)){
        Console.WriteLine("El valor no es numerico.");
        continue;
    }

    List<int> opciones = new List<int>() {0, 1, 2};
    if(!opciones.Contains(valor))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No es un valor permitido.");
        continue;
    }

    values[counter] = valor;
    counter++;

}
```

de esta foma si el valor ingresado no cumple con la validacion lo informas y usas el `continue` para volver a solicitar lo ingrese

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿No es mejor crear la lista con los valores admitidos afuera del while? de esa forma solo se crea una vez y no cada vez que entra al while.

Comment: @Luis en este caso si son valores fijos es verdad deberia estar definida por fuera, pero tampoco es que haria mucha diferencia, pero si cambia si esa lista se toma de algun otra fuente como ser una consulta a una db, etc, lo que defino es solo un ejemplo, esta claro que siempre se puede mejorar, pero la base esta